# KendoUI TreeView trying to add dirty property to Poco and getting Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

Ok, so on a **Kendo UI treeview** i'm trying to add a property into my c# poco, but as soon as I do I get an **error** in **chrome dev tools**

> Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function

I was reading about adding to the model, so I added **dirty:"dirty"**

```
schema: {
     model: {
       id: "Id", 
       dirty: "dirty",
       hasChildren: "Id"
     }
}
```

Then C# poco  property added that causes the problem

```
public bool dirty { get; set; }
```

The reason that I want the dirty property in the first place is because I'm not using kendo sync() method,  and I see that when I spit out the datasource

```
console.log(mydatasource.data());
```

Then I see that "**dirty**" is in the array.

I have already done the same for **children**  and regardless if I expand the treeview or not ( has children only if expanding a node as it calls up mvc controller method)

```
// my children nodes
public List<Students> items { get; set; }
```

**items** is in the **array** that is generated and causes no problem..

Why is "**dirty**" a problem?

Comment: Try setting this property to schema: `parse: function(data) { if (!data) { data = []; } return data; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't use `dirty` as that was not a needed or good idea.